# Insert into table from select distinct query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 33 columns that has several duplicates so i am trying to remove all the duplicates this way because this select distinct query has the correct number of data.

```
    CREATE TABLE students (
school char(2),sex char(1),age int,address char(1),famsize char(3),
Pstatus char(1),Medu int,Fedu int,Mjob varchar,Fjob varchar,reason varchar,
guardian varchar,traveltime int,studytime int,failures char(1),
schoolsup varchar,famsup varchar,paid varchar,activities varchar,
nursery varchar,higher varchar,internet varchar,romantic varchar,
famrel int,freetime int,goout int,Dalc int,Walc int,
health int,absences int,id serial primary key)
```

I want to insert all values from this select distinct query
with 8 columns into a different empty table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ("school","sex","age","address","famsize","Pstatus","Medu","Fedu","Mjob","Fjob","reason","nursery","internet")
FROM students;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: If i use this i will only get the 8 values and i want all 33 values

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.
Are you trying to identify all records where a combination of 8 fields are unique?

Comment: I edited the question for further details

Comment: Do **not** put parentheses around the column names in the select list.  That creates a **single** column with an anonymous record structure.

Answer (score 6):

> *I want to insert all values from this select distinct query with 8 columns into a different empty table.*

Use `create table .. as select ...` if you want to create the table

```
create table new_table
as
SELECT DISTINCT school, sex, age, address, famsize, "Pstatus", "Medu", "Fedu", "Mjob", "Fjob", reason, nursery, internet
FROM students;
```

Other wise just use an insert based on a select:

```
insert into empty_table (school, sex, age, address, famsize, "Pstatus", "Medu", "Fedu", "Mjob", "Fjob", reason, nursery, internet)
SELECT DISTINCT school, sex, age, address, famsize, "Pstatus", "Medu", "Fedu", "Mjob", "Fjob", reason, nursery, internet
FROM students;
```

Very important: do **not** put parentheses around the columns in the select list - that creates a **single** column with an anonymous record type.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into destinationTable(dC1, dC2, dC3, dC4, dC5, dC6, dC7, dC8)
select sC1, sC2, sC3, sC4, sC5, sC6, sC7, sC8
from sourceTable
```

You can `join` the `table`s to get the 33 `column`s.